# Reverse for 'single' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-urls, django-3.0

I run this code and it works perfectly. I opened it a few days later again and it's throwing an error in all pages except the `add/` page.
Error code: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'single' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']` 
I tried reading other similar issues here but they didn't solve the problem

models.py

```
class Core(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    excerpt = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='core')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def get_absolute_urls(self):
        return reverse('core:single', args=[self.slug])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-published']
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('add/', views.AddView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('posts/', views.PostsView.as_view(), name='posts'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.SingleView.as_view(), name='single'),
]
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Core
    template_name = 'core/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'index'

class SingleView(DetailView):
    model = Core
    template_name = 'core/single.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'

class PostsView(ListView):
    model = Core
    template_name = 'core/posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

class AddView(CreateView):
    '''Basically a form. Someone types in and add new post'''
    model = Core
    template_name = 'core/add.html'
    fields = '__all__' #take all the fields from the db and put that into a form
    success_url = reverse_lazy('core:posts')
```

single.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 pt-5">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1600x900" alt="" class="card-img-top">
            <h2 class="pt-5">{{ post.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">  
        <div class="row">
            {% for core in index %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" alt="card image cap" class="card-img-top">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4><a href="{{ core.get_absolute_urls }}">{{ core.title }}</a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="">
                                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Sorry for the lengthy question

**2.** Secondly any suggestion to a material that can help me grasp a full understanding of Django URLs aside from Django own's documentation? URLs are giving me a lot of tough time

Comment: I guess you have a record with empty slug (empty string). I'd suggest you to change this pattern `<slug:slug>/` to something with a specific prefix, e.g. `single/<slug:slug>/`. Because `add`, `post` are perfect slug values. Also define prepopulate-options for this SlugField.

Comment: @Ivan Starostin Thanks for the reply. However, I am still confused about how to go about it. I did `single/<slug:slug>/` but still is throwing out an error

Comment: _I guess you have a record with empty slug (empty string)._ Take a look at your DB. `<slug:slug>` cannot accept empty string as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slug item in your URL.

However  your design your URL, that is how it should look like.

Comment: Firstly, your URL is structured badly. Not that that's the problem  though. The problem is, your URL needs a variable slug item in it.

Comment: There seems to be a record with empty slug field.

Comment: You may need to